# Though I am pretty sure that number of hits is increasing on my website the Alexa ranking is decreasing daily

Tags: google-analytics, ranking, alexa-internet

I have Google Analytics and server side analytics installed in its place and the results show that the number of hits have increase as compared to previous days. Though my Alexa ranking has reduced comparatively !!!

Is is that the Alexa ranking is only dependent on those who have installed Alexa Toolbars only? As such, most of my traffic is from mobile browsers, Alexa is not getting enough data?

Why is Instagram's Alexa Ranking(36) so high even though it is primarily mobile app based network? They don't even have a proper home page as such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Correct. Alexa will rank based on traffic monitored through alexa toolbars. And if mobile visits are increased it wont appear under alexa ranking.

Comment: any idea as to why is Instagram's Alexa ranking(36) is so high ?